# Replacing Kitchen Fan - Wiring Problems

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Replacing an old ceiling fan in a 1960's era house. Unfortunately I took out the old ceiling fan and didn't look at what was connected where. The old ceiling fan was a fan/light operating on 2 separate switches.

Wiring diagram looks like something I have not seen before

[image: Kitchen Wiring Diagram]

As you can see, the white/neutral in the power coming in is just capped off. Black/hot go into switch one, transfer to switch 2, and then white/neutral and black/hot out of switch 2 towards the fan. There is one extra wire near the fan that appears to be black/hot.

Any thoughts? When I try different combinations of wiring I am not having success in getting the fan to turn back on.

Comment: Is the black wire that goes between the switches connected to the lower terminal (where the white wire is) on the left switch?  If so, it looks like the switch on the right turned on the light, and if the light was on then the switch on the left would turn on the fan.  Is that how it worked?  Some weird wiring issues though - it looks like the black wire coming into the ceiling box from the right would be the neutral.

Comment: The black wire that goes between switches is connected to the lower terminal where the white wire exits. Previously one switch did manage the fan and other the light, so that makes sense.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the ceiling box?  Are you in the US or somewhere else?  Is this individual wires inside conduit, or Romex cables?  I'm very puzzled by the black wire that appears to be the neutral - are there any other wires coming in with that one?

Comment: One more question - do you have a voltmeter to measure voltage on the black wire where it enters the right switch, and the black wire entering the ceiling box from the right?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes? Something very strange indeed is going on here...

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for all the help. I think I figured this one out. There was one other set of wires in the box above the fan, about 4 grouped together. I assumed that was just being used as a junction. Turns out, that was my neutral. The white wire going into the box was just a dude, had no purpose. I didn't climb into the attic to see what they actually did to make the connection work like this. Thanks again for the help thinking through this.

Comment: @MarkWagner - You realize you still have a problem. Who ever installed the original fan used an illegal method to attach the neutral. All neutrals must be in the same cable and path of the switch legs. I would suggest you go out and buy a universal fan controller that operates on two wires and connect the neutral up properly.